# How change encoding in VSCode Output view when use msbuild task

Tags: visual-studio-code

I configure msbuild build task in VSCode

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "msbuild",
"args": [
    "IntegrationTests.sln"
],
"taskSelector": "/t:",
"showOutput": "always",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "showOutput": "always",
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
}
```

The task output is unreadable. The output text must be in Russian.
When I run msbuild command from the command line then all is well.

How can i change output encoding ?

[image]

Comment: This can be track via: https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/Detail/17922. Currently VSCode assumes that the output is in UTF8

Comment: Thanks @DirkBäumer. I posted this issue to VSCode today.

Comment: @Aleksei Semidotskii, did you resolve this issue? I have completely the same problem.